# In C, how does the read function "know" when there is nothing left to read?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent-child

In the below program (which is not mine, but one which I have modified), the child process makes two writes to the pipe. When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
Received string: Hello, world!
This is the child process.
```

How is it that the *read* performed by the parent process captures both of these strings from the pipe buffer? What (if anything) prevents the parent process from assuming after it has read the first string (or the first char of the first string for that matter) that there is nothing else to read from the buffer, and exiting?

Program in question:

```
int main(void)
{
    int     fd[2], nbytes;
    pid_t   childpid;
    char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    char    string2[] = "This is the child process.\n";
    char    readbuffer[80];

    pipe(fd);

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
            perror("fork");
            return 1;
    }

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
            /* Child process closes pipe's input file descriptor */
            close(fd[0]);

            /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
            write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)));
            write(fd[1], string2, (strlen(string2)+1));
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
            /* Parent process closes pipe's output file descriptor */
            close(fd[1]);

            /* Read in a string from the pipe */
            nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the parent reads and _might_ not read all the data - as it may not be there yet.  Parent reads what is there, at that point in time.  There may be more later.  Parent code does not test to see if there is more data.

Comment: Generally, you know you've read it all when the pipe is closed (and `read()` returns 0) or when you check that what you read is everything that was supposed to be sent (how you know that depends on your application).  A short read (less than you requested) would suggest you've read whatever was ready at the time, but there could be more later.

Comment: There's really nothing preventing it. Your code here just gets lucky, and should be improved.

Comment: regarding this line: 'pipe(fd);'  pipe is a system function so the returned value should always be checked (not the parameter) to assure the operation was successful.   0 on success, -1 on failure

Comment: the posted code fails to check the returned value from read(), so the read() could have failed and there would have been no notification of the failure.   Pipes have no concept of records, lines, etc, so the one call to read() reads everything available in the pipe. (I.E. the output from both calls to fprintf()) and the following printf() outputs everything that was read.  Note: read() does NOT append a '\0' to the input data. So the code should (for robustness) always append a '\0', using the 'nbytes' variable to determine where to place that '\0'

Answer (score 2):

The key here is the `read()` buffer size `80`.

Usually `read()` *block* the process which is calling it (is set in a sleeping status) until certain conditions doesn't happen, for example:

- the requested buffer is full
- there's less data than requested (`EOF`) or an error occurred
- a signal wake the process (as `^C`), this may be  your case, the child process exit and the *system* send a *broken pipe* signal to the parent (the process wake and `read()` get the whole buffer)

Note that those conditions depends on the subsystem you are reading from, in your case a `pipe`. Subsystem which may have different properties, like buffer size. An absurd example: if pipe buffer size on *kernel side* was less than or equal to your first write, the *reading* process would have wake up earlier returning a truncated buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I love this question. It makes me remember old time ...

Meta-answer: It does only know, if the stream is closed

Answer: your process reads all it can/has to read, no end stops at '\n'

But I suppose, you want to write/read records.

Despite others I try to answer without distinguishing types of streams. I make a disclaimer here:

it all depends on OS and stream type - and the options opening on both (!) sides

Basic:

Lets say one process writes an other reads - easy enough.

No is not.

Imagine - always ;-) - they put there chars (bytes) into the stream as they want and can - slowly - fast - one by one or all they buffered.

and you read it - no - not you and not your program - in between - byte by byte or on block or how the layer in between likes.

So if you want a record, there a only three possibilities:

1. make an end char(byte) - block seperator,
2. make the records fix length,
3. the old two-byte-length then read the rest

Answer again:

in your case the child puts all chars in the stream the parent read them and over - why should one of them make a break?

Solution:

Depending on the OS and language and libs, you sometimes can tell the OS to make an / accept an end char (like \n) - sometimes your write read functions do that for you

Answer (score 0):

The parent will read a maximum of 80 bytes. So the first `write` system call (and also the second) will place the first string in the kernel buffer relative to the pipe. The `read` system call will read a maximum of 80 bytes, so it will ask to the kernel for the data, and the kernel will return the first 80 bytes of data in the buffer (so it is impossible to read only the first character of the string with a single write of the entire string and a single *blocking* read of 80 bytes).

As you stated there is no synchronization between the child and the parent.
In fact on my linux system your program sometimes print only the first string, sometimes its print both.

The problem is a classic *Race Condition* problem, sometimes the child will write only the first string, then the parent is scheduled and it will read the first string, then the program will end (or the control will return to the child after the `read`, the child will write the second string to the pipe buffer but no one will actually read the data).

You should place some synchronization functions in your program, an example can be to place a wait for the child after the `close(fd[1]);`

```
[...]
else
{
      /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
      close(fd[1]);

      /* Synchronize parent and child */
      wait(NULL);

      /* Read in a string from the pipe */
      nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
      printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
}
[...]
```

Then the parent will read the data only when the two strings are correctly placed in the buffer.

Comment: From the linux `read()` manpage: On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal)

I'm sorry if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I've actually tried the OP program and I've the Race condition problem above...that's weird!

Comment: This isn't really a good solution since the `wait()` makes the pipe almost pointless.

Comment: after the child is terminated, the pipe has one end (the input end) completely closed.  Then the data cannot be read from the pipe.  I.E. do NOT wait for the child to terminate until after all bytes read from pipe.

Comment: @user3629249 Closing the write end of a pipe does not prevent the data already written to it from being read.

Comment: For clarification what you were saying was correct, I believe my understanding was wrong. I still think `wait()` is a bad idea, in this situation it misses the point of a pipe, and in general it will cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of how to write to a pipe.

This example is for parent writing to child, but the logic is very similar, regardless of the data flow direction.

```
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child to exit */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Amongst other things, this means the caller to read() will get a returned value of 0 when everything is read from the pipe.

this also means the reader to read in a loop until a error condition indication is returned or a 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

> ... how does the read function “know” when there is nothing left to read?

On success `read()` returns a much as available in the underlying object but not more then requested.

From [`man 3 read` (POSIX)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html):

> Upon successful completion, where nbyte is greater than 0, read() shall mark for update the st_atime field of the file, and shall return the number of bytes read. This number shall never be  greater
>          than  nbyte. The value returned may be less than nbyte if the number of bytes left in the file is less than nbyte, if the read() request was interrupted by a signal, or if the file is a pipe or FIFO
>          or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available for reading.

Comment: @Veltas: The way the code works, that is sometime printing less sometime more, is perfect to demonstrate what the specification above state: "*The value returned may be less than nbyte  .... if the file is a pipe or FIFO or special file and has fewer than nbyte bytes immediately available for reading.*" All good. The OP's question is not "*why does it sometime print more, sometimes less?*", but "*how does the read function “know” when there is nothing left to read?*" I give the answer, it's in the specs, as mostly ... ;-)

Comment: @Veltas: Also this statement "*OP's code doesn't work*" is highly subjective. The code compiles without warnings, there is no UB invoked when running this nice race. And as I see no spec saying it ought to always print the same output, I'd consider the code working fine.

Comment: Okay I understand now, I will delete my comments. Also: I think a good answer would include an example of how to read the rest of the pipe until the output file descriptors are exhausted.

Comment: And I still say the code doesn't work. OP appears unaware of the race, my previous comment's suggestion would satisfy addressing that.